# How does the Sleeping Giant work?

Tags: borderlands-3

[image]

The "Sleeping Giant" SMG in Borderlands 3 has the following white text:

> Reloading has a chance to grant weapon bonuses

I have been running with it for a while and have yet to figure out what these elusive "bonuses" are. Will I be notified when it is triggered? Are the bonuses subtle damage boosts? How does this gun work?

Answer (score 5):

You won't be notified at all. The bonuses vary wildly from 3x damage to 2x fire rate. But some aren't buffs. A few people have reported a drop in damage. I can't say I have ever had this happen personally. The way the gun works is every time you reload it you get a new random bonus until you reload again. As far as I can tell there is no way to predict what bonus it will take.

On a completely different note, this thing gives a good bonus paired with the Moze's "Some for the road" perk, which alone is quite powerful.

Comment: Hey, welcome on Arqade SE. Have you any source for the bonus?